# Lucene Grails Searchable plugin build index for part of the table

Tags: grails, lucene, searchable, compass-lucene

I have a searchable domain class mapped to a table that has a flag column. Currently, when Lucene creates an index it generates a query like this (returns all data in the table):

```
        select this_.id as id0_0_, 
               this_.flag as flag2_0_0_, 
               this_.email as email0_0_, this_.first_name as first6_0_0_, this_.last_name as last8_0_0_ 
        from ais_person this_ 
        order by this_.id asc
```

Is it possible to build an index for only those rows which contain a specific flag value, so that the generated query would look like this:

```
    select this_.id as id0_0_, 
           this_.flag as flag2_0_0_, 
           this_.email as email0_0_, this_.first_name as first6_0_0_, this_.last_name as last8_0_0_ 
    from ais_person this_ 
    where this_.flag = 'Y' 
    order by this_.id asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i think you can do that. Following is the pseudo-code.

```
   Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(Field.Text("flag", Y));
```